# Exibir apenas segundo campo do field choises

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Na minha model possuo uma lista de opção e quando exibo ela no template aparece assim: "("D", "Devagar",)" e gostaria que fosse exibido apenas "("Devagar")".

**Atualmente**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como deve ficar**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Model.py**

```py
class Perfil(models.Model):
    vel = (
        ("D", "Devagar",),
        ("N", "Normal"),
        ("R", "Rápido "),
        ("S", "Super Rapido (Cuidado!)"),
    )

    velocidade = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=vel, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Velocidade')
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Perfil

def account(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    perfil = Perfil.objects.get(usuario_id=user_id)
    
    return render(request, 'core/account.html', {'nome': user_id, 'dados':perfil })
```

**home.html**

```html
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    {% for opcao in dados.vel %}
        <option data-select2-id="{{opcao}}">{{ opcao }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como demonstrado na [documentação da *template tag* `for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) você pode desempacotar (*unpacking*) os items que você está iterando sobre.

Como no seu caso, cada item é uma tupla, você poderia desempacotar a tupla em dois valores e usá-los:

```
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    {% for opcao_id, opcao_valor in dados.vel %}
        <option data-select2-id="{{ opcao_id }}">{{ opcao_valor }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz o for na opção você está iterando dentro de uma tupla de tuplas, sendo assim eu imagino que você queira fazer assim:

```
{% for opcao in dados.vel %}
    <option data-select2-id="{{opcao.0 }}">{{ opcao.1 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

O opcao.0 pega o primeiro item da tupla então no caso da tupla ("D","Devagar") ele vai pegar o "D" e o 1 pega o segundo item da tupla, no caso o "Devagar".